# Sending Jade text data from Node/Express is rendering as open/close HTML tags

Tags: node.js, express, pug, fs

Using `fs` I'm opening a simple text file with a single line of text. The console.log of the returned `data` looks correct, but when passing it into a Jade template via `res.render`, the view shows it in the textarea as open and close tags (so it appears twice). It's meant to just be the simple line of text.

Router:

```
router.get('/userlogin', auth, function(req, res, next) {

  function getData() {
    fs.readFile('./views/news.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {

      if (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
      }

      else {
        console.log("Found file! Contents: " + data);
        res.render('components/editor', { title: 'Simple News Editor', news: data });
      }
    });
  }

getData();

});
```

and then the current jade template:

```
extends ../layout

block content

  div(class="editor-header")
    h1 Simple News Editor

  div(class="editor-content")
    label(for="news-textarea")
      textarea(id="news-textarea")
        #{news}
```

The data is being passed into the template just fine, the issue is that it's rendering a textarea with the `data` from the `fs` call looking like this inside of the textarea:

```
<This is a test></This is a test>
```

I'm not sure where this open/close tag thing is happening and I've tried calling `.toString()` on the data in both the router function and the jade variable itself.

I must be missing something simple, but I can't seem to find the right search terms to get an answer about why this would be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a pipe `|` character is required before the interpolation happens. It's the same as if you were hardcoding text into the textarea.

So:

```
...
label(for="news-textarea")
  textarea(id="news-textarea")
    | #{news}
```

Resolves the issue.